# How to properly sort facet boxplots by median?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the 'diamonds' dataset that comes with R. When trying to sort the 'color' factor with respect to their price median it won't work.

This is what I got:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = reorder(color, -price, FUN=median), y = price)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  facet_wrap(~cut) + 
  ylim(0, 5500)
```

And it gives me that (not sorted at all): 
[image]

Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing?

Comment: have you checked here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45682405/sort-ggplot-boxplots-by-median-with-facets

Comment: I have, but couldnt make it work.

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a relatively simple way of achieving the requested arrangement using two helper function available [here](https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R)

```
reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}


scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}

library(tidyverse)
data(diamonds)

p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = reorder_within(color, price, cut, median), y = price)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 5) + 
  scale_x_reordered()+
  facet_wrap(~cut,  scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

using `ylim(0, 5500)` will remove a big part of the data resulting in different box plots which will interfere with any formerly defined order. If you wish to limit an axis without doing so it is better to use:

```
p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 5500))
```

this results in:

[image]

If you really intend to remove a big part of data and keep the arrangement, filter the data prior the plot:

```
diamonds %>%
  filter(price < 5500) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder_within(color, price, cut, median), y = price)) + 
  geom_boxplot(width = 5) + 
  scale_x_reordered()+
  facet_wrap(~cut,  scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great solution. It was not working for a while in my case. It took me a while to realize that my data's NA were affecting the calculations. I added `FUN = function(x) fun(x, na.rm=T)` to the first helper. :)

Comment: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547448/r-for-the-same-code-labels-q1-median-appear-on-one-computer-but-dont-appea thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = reorder(color, -price, FUN=median), y = price)) + 
      geom_boxplot() + 
      facet_wrap(~cut) + 
      ylim(0, 5500)
  levels(diamonds$color) # "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J"
  diamonds$color <- reorder(diamonds$color, -diamonds$price, FUN=median)
  levels(diamonds$color)  # "J" "I" "H" "F" "G" "D" "E"
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(x =color, y = price))+
      geom_boxplot() + 
      facet_wrap(~cut) + 
      ylim(0, 5500)
```

In fact what you have the following order

```
  ggplot(diamonds, aes(x =color, y = price))+
      geom_boxplot() + 
      ylim(0, 5500)
```

But the answer from missuse is very nice.

Comment: can you please take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547448/r-for-the-same-code-labels-q1-median-appear-on-one-computer-but-dont-appea thanks