# Helper functions for reordering box plots within facets not working in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I found 2 helper functions to help me reorder the box plots within ggplot2 facets, based on ascending mean in this page: [How to properly sort facet boxplots by median?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47090344/how-to-properly-sort-facet-boxplots-by-median)

However, this doesn't seem to be working for me, and is giving me a weird plot. Hoping someone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(agricolae)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)

#FULL DATA SET LOADING WITH REPLICATES
totalstarch2 = read.csv("totalstarch3.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = T)
totalstarch2$locyear = as.factor(paste(totalstarch2$location," 
",totalstarch2$year,sep=''))
View(totalstarch2)
str(totalstarch2)

#helper functions for reordering within facet
reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}


scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}

#draw box plot with genotype as facets
a=ggplot(totalstarch2,aes(x=reorder_within(starchdry,locyear, genotype), y=starchdry, 
color=locyear))+
geom_point()+
geom_boxplot()+
facet_wrap(~genotype, scales= "free_x", nrow=1, ncol=10)+
scale_y_continuous("Total starch % (dry basis)",limits = c(20,70), breaks = 
seq(20,70,5))+
theme_classic()+
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, color = "black"))+
scale_x_discrete("Environment")+
labs(color="Environment", title="A")+
theme(axis.title = element_text(size=14, color="black"),
    axis.text = element_text(size=10, color="black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1),
    legend.title = element_text(size=14),
    legend.text = element_text(size=10),
    title =element_text(size=14, face='bold'))
a
```

The data set I used is attached here: [Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14BzUI3zw2ztnQRyN4FT4DwA9dHEM0wMr/view?usp=sharing)

[image: This is what I am getting]

[image: This is how it needs to look like ideally, with the reordering within each facet]

Comment: you omitted `scale_x_reordered` from the `ggplot2` call. Please comment if this solved your problem - if yes I would vote to close as a typo that can not be reproduced.

Comment: Hi I tried with scale_x_reordered function which is not actually producing any plot at all.

Comment: The dataset provided in the link only has 4 rows and is already summarized and in each case `min_starch` = `max_starch` = `starchdry`. What kind of box plot do you expect?